# SD card map for 2011 Nissan Rogue

Tags: nissan, car, gps, rogue

I just bought a Nissan Rogue that comes with a GPS navigation system, the problem is, the SD card's missing, I've got three questions:

1 - Can I use any SD card of the same size with the Nissan map in it?

2 - If question number 1 doesn't apply, do I need to get a Nissan SD card that is from the same year (2011), or I can use any other Nissan SD card from a 2016 Nissan Rogue for example?

3 - And last but not least if I need to buy the 2011 SD card for 2011 Nissan Rogue, how will I be able to update the maps?

Comment: Check the Nissan Owners Portal for parts and info.  I can look for parts and data on  my wife's 2016 Rogue.  It shows SD card MAP as $149.  You should be able to compare part numbers for latest release.   The forum lists that updates are sold yearly and not free (how annoying).  I had also read the reader will take up to a 64Gb.  Was also disappointed on the fact the card had to remain in the slot to work.

Comment: I don't recommend to download the map data from the internet, put it on an SD card you may have lying around and just see if it works; because while it doesn't cost anything, it may be illegal...

Answer (score 2):

I own a 2011 Rogue. You have to buy the upgraded sd card everytime you want to update the maps. If you buy the $149 one from Nissan parts they will send you the most recent year. The system does not do updates.